# Java or C equivalent of MATLAB's robustfit

Tags: java, math, matlab, linear-regression, outliers

MATLAB has a magnificent [`robustfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/robustfit.html) function that solves the problem of excluding outliers with linear regression fitting. Is there anything similar written in Java or C (or in language X that could be adopted)?

Answer (score 2):

[Numerical Recipes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521880688) has an implementation of robust fit.  It's written in C/C++, so you should be able to port it over to Java without too much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an algorithm, a math library or a way to call matlab from java?

Comment: Whoops, that was supposed to be a comment.

Comment: I'm looking for "anything similar written in Java or C (or language X)". That is, an implementation that I could use in my programs.